# Facebook App : Problem with storing user info

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-fql

I want to store basic user info like name and proxied email into my MySQL database.
Here's my code

```
$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
$user = $facebook->require_login($required_permissions = 'publish_stream','status_update','email');

$con = mysql_connect("xxxx","xxxxx","xxxxx");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("xxx_userdb", $con);
//Uptil Here it is working fine...No problem with db connection

$fql_firstname = "select first_name from user where uid = '$user'";
$fql_lastname = "select last_name from user where uid = '$user'";
$fql_email = "select proxied_email from user where uid = '$user'";


$fql_fname_result = $facebook->api_client->fql_query($fql_firstname);
$fql_lname_result = $facebook->api_client->fql_query($fql_lastname);
$fql_email_result = $facebook->api_client->fql_query($fql_email);

echo "<pre>FQL Result:" . print_r($fql_fname_result,true) . "</pre>";
echo "<pre>FQL Result:" . print_r($fql_lname_result,true) . "</pre>";
echo "<pre>FQL Result:" . print_r($fql_email_result,true) . "</pre>";
```

Here's the output I get

```
FQL Result:

FQL Result:

FQL Result:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you passing your API key and API Secret?

Comment: Then what do you pass here? `$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);`

Comment: API key and application secret key...you said something about session key..

Comment: Yes, you need to either pass a userid (FB `uid`) or Session Key (if it's a desktop application) to Facebook else Facebook won't know who you are requesting.

Comment: Also, are you using Facebook Connect?

Comment: k...so I am passing API key and API Secret...why am I not getting the output?...No I am not using Facebook Connect

Answer (score 1):

From my investigation, here is what I **think** might be your problem.

In Facebook API `uid` is `int` and **not** a string so your FQL should be specifying a uid of int (but you applied it as a string).

Change

```
$fql_firstname = "select first_name from user where uid = '$user'";
$fql_lastname = "select last_name from user where uid = '$user'";
$fql_email = "select proxied_email from user where uid = '$user'";
```

To

```
$fql_firstname = "select first_name from user where uid = $user";
$fql_lastname = "select last_name from user where uid = $user";
$fql_email = "select proxied_email from user where uid = $user";
```

I hope `$user` returns the `uid`.

---

**Observation update**

Also, calling `fql_query` returns an array of data, so (just in case) why don't you try (not really sure if I'm correct in PHP)

```
echo "<pre>FQL Result:" . print_r($fql_fname_result[0],true) . "</pre>";
echo "<pre>FQL Result:" . print_r($fql_lname_result[0],true) . "</pre>";
echo "<pre>FQL Result:" . print_r($fql_email_result[0],true) . "</pre>";
```

Comment: Yes $user return the uid....I had also thought about this ...but unfortunately this doesn't help..

Comment: Then I'm all out of options. Your code looks correct in all respect. Sorry!

Comment: Do I need to use an XML parser like cUrl?...Did this code work for you?